# How to use Jquery Selector as a variable in a function? Getting undefined?

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I want to grab each day of the week (div, I only have 1) and create a string to put in a database. so my final output is a string something like 9:00am to 5:00pm. I'm trying to concatenate all the select options by using .test selector

```
                <div class="col-sm-7 date"  id="sunDiv">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "sunday" id="sunday" placeholder="" value="" required >
                <select class = 'test'>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option selected>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>11</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                </select> :
                <select class = 'test'>
                    <option>00</option>
                    <option>15</option>
                    <option>30</option>
                    <option>45</option>
                </select>
                <select class = 'test'>
                    <option>AM</option>
                    <option >PM</option>
                </select> to
                <select class = 'test'>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option selected>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>11</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                </select> :
                <select class = 'test'> 
                    <option>00</option>
                    <option>15</option>
                    <option>30</option>
                    <option>45</option>
                </select>
                <select class = 'test'> 
                    <option>AM</option>
                    <option selected>PM</option>
                </select>
                <input type="checkbox" name="closed" id="closed" value="closed" class="closed"><span>&nbsp Closed</span>&nbsp &nbsp 
                <input type="checkbox" name="unknown" id="unknown" value="unknown" class="unknown"><span>&nbspUnknown</span>
            </div>
<button id = 'testbtn' class = 'btn btn-info'>Test</button>

    $('#testbtn').on('click', function(){
        grabTimeStr("sunDiv")

    function grabTimeStr(day){
        var arr4 =[]
        day = $('#'+day).attr('id')
        console.log(day)
        $('.test',$(day).parent()).each(function(value){                   
            arr4.push((`${this.value}`)); 
            console.log((`${this.value}`))
        }) 
    }
```

I figuered it out in the below code. But want to do it by running the function for each day.

```
        $('#testbtn').on('click', function(){
       
        var arr5 = []

        $('.date').each(function(index, value) {
            var arr4 =[]                
            console.log($(this).attr('id'))
            //Have to scope parent div.
            $('.test',$(this).parent()).each(function(value){                   
                arr4.push((`${this.value}`)); 
                  console.log((`${this.value}`))
               }) 
            x = arr4[0]+":"+arr4[1]+ " "+ arr4[2]+" to "+arr4[3]+":"+arr4[4] + " "+ arr4[5] 
            arr4 =[]       
            console.log(x)
            arr5.push(x) 
        })   
    console.log(arr5)
```

Comment: whats the expected output you want ?

Comment: It should be the id of the div. "sunDiv"
in the grabTimeStr function if i put in $('#sunDiv') and take out the 'day' parameter. It will return sunDiv in the console.

Comment: how can a variable `sundiv` (not assigned to anything) can act like an `id` - `$('sundiv')` selector - Can you explain that first ?

Comment: ah man so stupid. I get it now. should be 
   $('#testbtn').on('click', function(){
        grabTimeStr('sunDiv') )}

Comment: Not really .Thats not correct too. this will be undefined as well (`$('#testbtn').on('click', function(){ grabTimeStr('sunDiv') )}`) => Tell me what are you trying to do first. Whats your end goal with this ?

Comment: I don't know if there is enough room here, but basically I want to run a block of code for each div.

Comment: Nice........... :/

Comment: I added it in the og post

Comment: @AlwaysHelping here is my https://jsfiddle.net/54n61c70/

Comment: Sure let me check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219577/discussion-between-adamgis-and-alwayshelping).

Comment: See the discussion chat. I added the solution for you.

Comment: I see thank you I think this should work! Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help as always. Happy coding